# How to create a form with blurred background and a sharp panel inside it?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, modal-dialog

When you set the opacity of the form it will affect all of it's child controls. Now I need exclude my panel inside the form from it.

The ultimate goal is to make a dialog box with a blurry background.

Comment: The question that this question is marked as a duplicate of, suggests using another blurry form in background which is not quite what I had in mind (but it works).

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate dialog box, and float it over the blurred form.